# how to select only a b c d e f g with keycode on my javascript code

Tags: javascript, keycode

I have this code how select the B letter on my keyboard
and I would select the a b c d e f g

I'm sure it's simple to do this but I don't know yet how to select only few letters than one or all

Can you help me change the keycode line?

```
new PressAndHold({
  duration: 500, 
  keyCode: 66,
  onCancel: () =>  $('#status-bar').removeClass('is-animating'),
  onStart: () => $('#status-bar').addClass('is-animating'),
  onSuccess: () => { 
    $('#status-bar').removeClass('is-animating')
    $('#footer').addClass('is-showing')
  },
  keepAlive: true
});

$('html').click(() => {
  $('#footer').removeClass('is-showing');
})
```

Comment: What is `PressAndHold`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "how select the B letter on my keyboard"? Are you saying that you want to simulate a key press? And, if so, why? Why not just perform the task(s) that pressing B (or any other letter) would initiate?

Comment: thanks for your questions, 
you can understand my probleme here 

I you play with this code : https://codepen.io/midniteio/pen/xgROWX

Comment: It's absolutely unclear what you're up to. *" I would select the a b c d e f g"* means what exactly? Please, imagine you're reading your own question not knowing anything about your task or issue.

Comment: add this to your javascript, then open console & when you press a key you can see the code `document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey); function logKey(e) { console.log(e.code,e.which) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a loop?

```
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    new PressAndHold({
      duration: 500, 
      keyCode: 65 + i,
      onCancel: () =>  $('#status-bar').removeClass('is-animating'),
      onStart: () => $('#status-bar').addClass('is-animating'),
      onSuccess: () => { 
        $('#status-bar').removeClass('is-animating')
        $('#footer').addClass('is-showing')
      },
      keepAlive: true
    });
}

$('html').click(() => {
  $('#footer').removeClass('is-showing');
})


$('html').click(() => {
  $('#footer').removeClass('is-showing');
})
```